# Iterate two list in single for loop, how will do in Java 8

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

Below code How we will do in Java 8

```
List<String> epResponse;  
MatcherResponse bwResponse;  
getTempIds -> is type of map;
for (int i=0; i<l2ExtRequest.getPoint().size(); i++) {  
        MatcherResponse bwResponse = response.getTempIds().get(epResponse.get(i).getName());  
        l2ExtRequest.getPoint().get(i).getKage().getAttribute().setId(bwResponse.getId());
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason to convert this to any code involving streams. You would use an `IntStream` to generate a stream of index values, but it has no benefit. Your current code is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use `IntStream.range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`.

Example code:

```java
IntStream.range(0, l2ExtRequest.getPoint().size()).forEach(i -> {
    //put your code here
});
```